# dump certain telescope entry to 3rd party such as elastic search

Tags: laravel, elastic-stack

I am exploring the idea that capturing certain telescope entries (e.g. type = request) and save to 3rd party service such as Elastic Search.

Why? The hosting I am using does not support straight Logstash (or equivalent integration) and I need a way to access to request history. I can do this with MySQL but other tools such as Elastic Search provides more insights.

Any ideas where do I get started?

Comment: Hmm. Logstash shouldn't need your host's involvement (unless they're blocking *all* UDP, which seems unlikely). See https://medium.com/@bauernfeind.dominik/using-logstash-with-laravel-509c65065d52

Comment: @ceejayoz the official documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html says, the first step is to install Logstash which my hosting provider won't do. Or I may misunderstand your comment or didn't see it through.

Comment: Read the link I sent you. You can have Laravel send data directly to the Logstash endpoint. Elastic's docs are oriented towards streaming on-disk log files via a separate process. There's more than one way to skin a cat, as the saying goes.

Comment: @ceejayoz I see your point. what is an elegant way to log request info to Logstash only when Telescope Entry type is `request`?